# On the compactification of moduli space of vector bundles

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, moduli-spaces

Let $X$ be an irreducible, nodal curve over an algebraically closed field of genus at least $2$. Denote by $U(r,d)$ (resp. $U^0(r,d)$) the moduli space of torsion-free (resp. locally free) sheaves of degree $d$ and rank $r$ on $X$. Is there any known condition on $r,d$ under which, if $U(r,d) \not= \emptyset$, then $U^0(r,d) \not= \emptyset$?